# How to insert a jinja2 variable into an html element's attribute?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

My question relates to creating a `for` loop using a python dictionary and jinja2. I want to use the value of each key/value pair as the source attribute for an  element in HTML.

---HTML/jinja2---

```
{% for song, mp3 in song_dict.items() %}
        <li> {{ song }} :<audio controls> <source  src="{{ mp3 }}" type ="audio/mpeg"></audio>{{ mp3 }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

---

**python snippet**:

```
def home():    
    song_dict = {"Pumba":'"static/PUMBA_1.mp3"', "You're Feet":'"static/youre feet mix 1.8.17_1.mp3"',
     "ratatatatata":'"static/ratatat.mp3"',
    "12 | 8":'"static/12_8 NO CLICK.mp3"', "Sage to Your Internet" : '"static/sage to your internet.mp3"',
    "EB":'"static/EB DEMO MIX NO CLICK.mp3"'}

    return render_template("pet_friend.html",
                            song_list = song_list,
                            song_dict = song_dict
                            )
```

---

I can get text to print after the audio player, but I cannot pass the path to the src attribute of the audio element.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The path should be `'/static/PUMBA_1.mp3'` and not `'"static/PUMBA_1.mp3"'` (with a leading /)

But if you already store the files in a static folder, the easiest way to serve the files in jinja templates is to call this function : [`url_for('static',filename=your_file.mp3)`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/static/)

it creates a path automatically to your static folder and allows you to change it without modifying everything (so you can remove all 'static' in `song_dict`).

---

Jinja Template :

```
{% for song, mp3 in song_dict.items() %}
    <li>{{ song }}:<audio controls> 
                   <source src="{{ url_for('static',filename=mp3) }}" type ="audio/mpeg">
                   </audio>{{ mp3 }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

---

View (without every "static/" and double `' "" '`):

```
def home():
    song_dict = {"Pumba":'PUMBA_1.mp3', "You're Feet":'youre feet mix 1.8.17_1.mp3',
     "ratatatatata":'ratatat.mp3'}

    return render_template("pet_friend.html",
                            song_dict = song_dict
                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet.

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename = filename) }}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use dictionaries and lists in jinja, use it just like you do in python:

```
{{dictionary["key"]}}
{{mylist[index]}}
```

Will give the dictionary value where dictionary["key":"value"] and the item that is located on "index" respectively. Use "for" to loop through them as suggested on the other answers.